# covering space of a particular CW complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I am trying to find all connected covers of the following space $X$ (up to isomorphisms)
$X$ has one $0$-cell, two $1$-cells labeled $a$ and $b$, and three $2$-cells attached via $a^2$, $b^2$ and $aba^{-1}b ^{-1}$ respectively.

So far I have computed the fundamental group (the Klein-four group generated by $a$ and $b$). Since it has $3$ proper subgroups I wanted to find the corresponding covers, but had no luck so far..

Could someone help me with how to start?

Comment: What do you mean by "**find** the corresponding covers"? This is part of the point of my answer. I find the easiest way is to go via covering morphisms of groupoids, since a covering _map_ is modelled by a covering _morphism_. You could print out the appropriate section round p.590 of the pdf of the book I refer to. The 2-cells upstairs are determined by their boundary and the starting point.   The right hand picture represents the loop  upstairs   $(a,a)^{-1}(b,1)^{-1}(a,ab)(b,a)$ starting at $a$.

Answer (score 3):

One question is how to represent the cover! It is best first to use the $1$-dimensional part. So here on the left

[image: uni]

is a picture of the $1$-dimensional part of the  universal cover, taken from p. 590 of [Nonabelian Algebraic Topology](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/nonab-a-t.html), in a section on covering morphisms of groupoids.  The picture on the right is of the boundary of one of the cells covering your $2$-cell. An edge labelled of the form $(a, -)$ maps down to $a$.

Hope this enables you to draw the other pictures, and other examples.

Comment: Thanks for replying, although I am not entirely sure of your approach. I would like to be able to describe the CW structure of the covers.

Does your diagram show how the elements of the fundamental group get permutated? If yes, how does one see to which action this corresponds?

And in which way could I construct all the covers?

Comment: @heather: The common approach to covering spaces is via actions, which I find not so easy as covering morphisms of groupoids, see my book Topology and Groupoids. There a covering map is modelled by a covering morphism, which can be written down in this case. The 2-cells which cover your 2-cells in the base can be seen individually, via their boundary, but can't really be drawn all  at once. What one can easily see is how the loops =1-cells  lift, since one has unique path lifting. In particular, the right hand diagram shows the lift  starting at $a$ and covering  $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$.

Answer (score 2):

It may be helpful to think of $X$ as being the 2-skeleton of a suitable cell decomposition of the 4-manifold $\mathbb{RP}^2\times\mathbb{RP}^2$.  Then the universal cover will be a subcomplex of $S^2\times S^2$, and the other covers of $X$ can be viewed as subcomplexes of suitable quotients of the manifold $S^2\times S^2$.

Comment: That was a different strategy I tried, but failed again: I don't know how to see which action you use to see which subcomplex of $S^2$ x $S^2$ one gets..

Comment: The action of $\mathbb Z_2$ on each factor is by the antipodal map: $x\mapsto -x$.

Comment: But how can I find which subcomplex of $S^2$ x $S^2$ the universal cover is?

Comment: Isn't it in fact $S^2$x$S^2$ since the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ x $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is the same as the fundamental group of X?

Comment: Take the cell decomposition of the sphere into upper and lower hemisphere, where the equator is decomposed into a pair of semicircles.

Comment: But how does this give a universal cover of X? I get the two 2-cells that attached via $a^2$ and $b^2$, but do not see the third 2-cell coming into place?

Comment: The third cell is the product of the two 1-cells in each factor.  This is the universal cover because rp2 times rp2 has the right fundamental group!